# Installing PEAR and PHPUnit with xampp

Tags: php, installation, phpunit, pear

I am trying to get PHPUnit up and running the following are the steps I am currently following:

```
### Install new PEAR Version needed for PHPUnit 3.X
### Download:  http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar Save it under C:\xampp\php

Open a command prompt and go to C:\xampp\php
Type "php go-pear.phar" (Installs new PEAR)
Type "pear update-channels" (updates channel definitions)
Type "pear upgrade --alldeps" (upgrades all existing packages and pear)
Type "pear channel-discover components.ez.no" (this is needed for PHPUnit)
Type "pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com" (also needed by PHPUnit)
Type "pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de" (This IS phpunit)
Type "pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit" (installs PHPUnit and all dependencies)
```

This works up untill the point where I have to `pear upgrade --alldeps` after downloading all the bits it needs i get:#

```
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\data\Auth\Auth\Frontend
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Benchmark\doc
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\data\Cache\Container
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Cache_Lite\docs
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Calendar\docs\examples
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Config\docs
.....
```

My PHP directory is installed under `C:\xampp\php`

What do I need to change so that it knows the correct place to add these directories/ files?

Thanks

Comment: you need to add local variable `PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems the issue is not with PHPUnit but with your **pear installation** in general.

The user you run the install with does not have the privileges to create the needed folders.

Ether fix those permissions or start the cmd prompt with admin privileges (<kbd>windowsbutton</kbd> & enter "cmd" then <kbd>strg</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>) and rerun the commands.

Comment: You know the whole point of XAMPP and it's portability with USB stick is lost there if one needs to create `C:\PHP\Pear`, I did it too though I hate fighting against these systems. But still I'd like to see solution where it would use xampp directory and not some `C:\PHP`

Comment: You can change the directory by using `pear config-show` and related commands and see if you can get it to work. But given that many things in xampp and `pear` rely on fixed paths it's not going to be simple

Comment: strg is the ctrl key on some keyboards.

Answer (score 30):

To install in D:\xampp\php, set the following directory paths using pear config-set command

```
D:
cd D:\xampp\php
pear config-set doc_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\docs
pear config-set cfg_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\cfg
pear config-set data_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\data
pear config-set cache_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\cache
pear config-set download_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\download
pear config-set temp_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\temp
pear config-set test_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\tests
pear config-set www_dir d:\xampp\php\pear\www
```

Comment: thanks this help. to verify configuration first enter pear config-show (aris answer)

Answer (score 9):

this is a solution for a similar problem install propel orm in xampp. By default, pear tries install in c:\php\pear\data, and this folder don't exists, because pear is in c:\xampp\php\pear.

Show pear configutarion:

```
pear config-show
...
pear config-get data_dir
c:\php\pear\data
```

Change the pear configuration to:

```
pear config-set data_dir c:\xampp\php\pear\data
```

i hope this is useful ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Widows 8, make sure you opened a [command window as administrator](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-open-dos-command-prompt-window-as-administrator-in-windows-8/), otherwise dir creation will be silently rejected by the OS !

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get pear (and subsequently, phpunit) working by creating a [symlink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) in C:\ that points to the xamp php installation directory.  That makes everything that expects php to be in C:\php happy, while not breaking anything that expected php to be in xampp:

In cmd.exe, I typed:

```
C:\Windows>cd \
C:\>junction php C:\path\to\xampp\php
```

I updated my php.ini to use C:\php as the location for php.
I then [installed pear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796554/installing-pear-on-wampserver) (as a local installation, not system).
Once pear was installed, installing phpunit was simple:

```
C:\>pear channel-discover components.ez.no
C:\>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
C:\>pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

And then finally,

```
C:\>pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help follow the below link:
http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/7346/installing-phpunit-on-windows-xampp/p1

1. Open a command prompt and go to C:\xampp\php
2. Type "pear update-channels" (updates channel definitions)
3. Type "pear upgrade" (upgrades all existing packages and pear)
4. Type "pear channel-discover components.ez.no" (this is needed for PHPUnit)
5. Type "pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com" (also needed by PHPUnit)
6. Type "pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de" (This IS phpunit)
7. Type "pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit" (installs PHPUnit and all dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add

- `pear clear-cache` to *[clear the REST/XML-RPC cache](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.commands.php)* and
- `pear config-set preferred_state beta` to set the *[preferred package state to beta](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.config.php)*

This results in

```
php go-pear.phar
pear clear-cache 
pear update-channels
pear upgrade --alldeps -f 
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear config-set preferred_state beta
pear install --onlyreqdeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install PHPUnit via PEAR anymore https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457160/1783439

PHPUnit now comes as part of XAMPP.  You can find it here: `C:\xampp\php`.

At the command prompt:

```
cd c:\xampp\php
phpunit
```