# phpUnit:install:windows7: path problem

Tags: php, windows, phpunit

```
C:\Program Files\PHP>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
Did not download optional dependencies: ezc/ConsoleTools, use --alldeps to download automatically

downloading PHPUnit-3.5.13.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.5.13.tgz (118,553 bytes)
..........................done: 118,553 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\PHPUnit-3.5.13.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmp42BA.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmp42BA.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit"
```

Installator try to write to c:\Program directory instead of Except C:\Program Files.

How to solve? Possible somebody have phpunit.bat for installation.

Thank you

Comment: Most likely it's not liking the space in "program files". You'll have to tell it to use a different temporary directory, or specify it via the 8.3 shortened version that Windows still supports for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Marc B: Great idea! Thanks!!! Write answer ))) I will set 'V' on your answer.

Comment: @Marc As far as i know thats correct. Care to post it as an answer? :) --- Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801111/installing-pear-and-phpunit-with-xampp/5801138#5801138

Comment: @edorian: Related, but answer does not explain solution. just open commd prompt, it is not solution.

Comment: I was rather going for the "you need admin rights to for pear to work in certain folders"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's not liking the space in "program files". You'll have to tell it to use a different temporary directory, or specify it via the 8.3 shortened version that Windows still supports for backwards compatibility.