# PEAR package install fails

Tags: php, console, phpunit, package, pear

i try to install packages `from pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools`

First of all command `pear config-get php_dir` returns `D:\Users\xampp\php\pear`
and I do not have rights to install on `C` drive.

Then according the instructions from http://phpqatools.org/
I enter :

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools
```

I have also tried to enter:
`pear install --alldeps pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools`

But result of all these attempts is a failure...

This is a log:

```
Package "pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit" has no releases
Unknown remote channel: pear.pdepend.org
Unknown remote channel: pear.phpmd.org
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
Package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/Text_Template" has
no releases
Package "pear.phpunit.de/phpcpd" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator" has no releases
Package "pear.phpunit.de/phpcpd" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer" has no releases
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
Package "pear.phpunit.de/phploc" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator" has no releases
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
Package "pear.phpqatools.org/PHP_CodeBrowser" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator" has no rel
eases
Failed to download pear/Text_Highlighter within preferred state "stable", latest release is version
 0.7.3, stability "beta", use "channel://pear.php.net/Text_Highlighter-0.7.3" to install
Package "pear.phpqatools.org/PHP_CodeBrowser" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit" has no releases
Package "pear.phpqatools.org/PHP_CodeBrowser" dependency "pear.php.net/PhpDocumentor" has no releas
es
Package "pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer" has no releases
Package "pear.phpunit.de/DbUnit" dependency "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit" has no releases
Package "pear.phpunit.de/DbUnit" dependency "pear.symfony-project.com/YAML" has no releases
WARNING: "pear/DB" is deprecated in favor of "pear/MDB2"
WARNING: "pear/Auth_SASL" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Auth_SASL2"
phpqatools/phpqatools requires package "channel://pear.pdepend.org/PHP_Depend"
phpqatools/phpqatools requires package "channel://pear.phpmd.org/PHP_PMD"
phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools" (versi
on >= 1.6)
phpunit/phpcpd requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools" (version >= 1.6)
phpunit/phploc requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools" (version >= 1.6)
phpunit/phploc can optionally use PHP extension "bytekit"
phpqatools/PHP_CodeBrowser can optionally use package "pear/Text_Highlighter" (version >= 0.7.1)
downloading PHP_CodeBrowser-1.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_CodeBrowser-1.0.3.tgz (172,253 bytes)
.....................................done: 172,253 bytes
downloading PHP_CodeSniffer-1.3.6.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_CodeSniffer-1.3.6.tgz (352,931 bytes)
...done: 352,931 bytes
downloading DbUnit-1.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download DbUnit-1.1.2.tgz (41,895 bytes)
...done: 41,895 bytes
downloading Console_CommandLine-1.1.3.tgz ...
Starting to download Console_CommandLine-1.1.3.tgz (38,507 bytes)
...done: 38,507 bytes
downloading Log-1.12.7.tgz ...
Starting to download Log-1.12.7.tgz (46,898 bytes)
...done: 46,898 bytes
downloading DB-1.7.14.tgz ...
Starting to download DB-1.7.14.tgz (133,103 bytes)
...done: 133,103 bytes
downloading MDB2-2.4.1.tgz ...
Starting to download MDB2-2.4.1.tgz (119,790 bytes)
...done: 119,790 bytes
downloading Mail-1.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download Mail-1.2.0.tgz (23,214 bytes)
...done: 23,214 bytes
downloading Net_SMTP-1.6.1.tgz ...
Starting to download Net_SMTP-1.6.1.tgz (13,164 bytes)
...done: 13,164 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\tests\PHP_CodeSniffer\CodeSniffer\Core\File
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\DbUnit\Samples\BankAccountDB\_files
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\data\Console_CommandLine\data
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Log\docs
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\DB\doc
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\MDB2\docs\examples
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\tests\Mail\tests
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Net_SMTP\docs
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\data\PHP_CodeBrowser\templates\css
```

I don't understand why install tries to mkdir on `C:\php\pear\` and also how to solve problems with unknown remove channels...

Comment: I solved a similar (but not the same) problem by manually deleting PEAR's cache (located at: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\pear`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way I found to get pear working when using Xamp is do delete the folder and reinstall it from scratch. The pear client (for a long time the very very broken 1.9.2 version) doesn't work properly even when in the excepted location but there is no sane way to fix it when you install xamp somewhere else as the path is set in way to many files.

Follow the guide on http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php.

Download  [**`http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`**](http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar),  execute it, select `system` wide install and adapt all the pathes to your location.

Once that is working and `pear version` reports `1.9.4` use

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install --force --alldeps pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools
```

to "fix" anything the old installation left over.

---

Just using that version of pear should fix all your Package and channel troubles too.

It it, for some reason, doesn't use

```
pear channel-discover $everyChannelThatDoesNotWork
pear channel-update $thatChannel
```

for everything that gets reported as a problem.

Comment: update didn't worked but complete remove of pear and install from scratch - yes.

Comment: Woah thanks ! This is by far the easiest way to install those never-ending qa packages. Best answer.

Answer (score 8):

If, like it was for me, running all the pear config-set commands still result in this error:

> failed to mkdir
>   C:\php\pear\tests\PHP_CodeSniffer\CodeSniffer\Core\File

then there is a simple solution which took me a while to figure out:

**Run your terminal as administrator**

Really, thats the solution. Then like others said: goto c:\xampp\php in your terminal and type following commands:

```
pear config-set doc_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\docs
pear config-set cfg_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\cfg
pear config-set data_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\data
pear config-set man_dir C:\xampp\php\local\man
pear config-set test_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\tests
pear config-set www_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\www

pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

Comment: @Joery this was definitely the issue

Answer (score 5):

Try to correct the config paths with following commands:

```
pear config-show

pear config-create / C:\xampp\php\pear.ini

pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set doc_dir c:\xampp\php\pear\docs
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set bin_dir c:\xampp\php
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set ext_dir c:\xampp\php\ext
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set php_dir c:\xampp\php\pear
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set cache_dir c:\xampp\php\cache
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set cfg_dir c:\xampp\php\cfg
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set data_dir c:\xampp\php\data
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set download_dir c:\xampp\php\download
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set php_bin c:\xampp\php\php.exe
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set temp_dir c:\xampp\php\tmp
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set test_dir c:\xampp\php\pear\tests
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set www_dir c:\xampp\php\pear\www

pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-show
```

Every pear command should use `-c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini` parameter, for example:

```
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini config-set auto_discover 1
pear -c c:\xampp\php\pear.ini install pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to delete the PEAR cache manually

```
pear clear-cache
```

clears the pear cache without having to go searching for the cache manually.

This solved the response I was getting when trying to download packages from the Structures channel which was

```
 no release for package ....
```

which indicated to me that pear had no new release for that particular package which had already been recorded as being on my system, although not successfully installed.

Also changing the *preferred state* from stable to devel using

```
pear config-set preferred_state devel
```

allowed installation of all the packages I required, most of which are either devel or alpha

Hope this helps someone from wasting nearly a day that this has cost me getting to the bottom of why I was getting the "No releases" response.

Answer (score 1):

Pear isn't configured properly. I remember XAMPP's install of pear not working out of the box.

See [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.config.php) for guidance on how to set the required variables properly. Find the ones that are set to a default value, like `C:\php\<something>` and change them to folders in XAMPP's pear/php installation.

Comment: You might need to change the config file manually.
See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8246271/925231).