# Unable to install php solr extension

Tags: php, solr

Using `pecl install -n solr` gives

`No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/solr"
install failed`

Also tried `pear install pecl/solr` which gives the same output :

`No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/solr"
install failed`

I'm using a Mac and php56.

Output of `pecl -V`

`PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.6.25
Zend Engine Version: 2.6.0
Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; 
root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Another important piece of information is that, `pear` and `pecl` were not available in my system, so I installed them using

`sudo php /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar -d /usr/local/lib/php -b /usr/local/bin`

**Update**

Tried `sudo pecl install -n solr` and now it seems to go one step further

`Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
ERROR: phpize failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily stumbled upon

[PEAR package install fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318446/pear-package-install-fails)

which led to execute
`pear list-upgrades` which showed some kind of permission issue with cache directory, manually created the directory using `sudo` at the specified location (`/private/tmp/pear/cache`)

And then used sudo to install the solr extension as `sudo pecl install -n solr` which threw the following error :

`Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.`

`brew install autoconf` followed by `sudo pecl install solr` worked.