# PEAR config-set error

Tags: php, xampp, pear

- OS: Win 7
- XAMPP 1.7.7 portable
- Windows command prompt
- D: is the thumb drive

I'm trying to follow this [post to fix PEAR settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801111/installing-pear-and-phpunit-with-xampp/8246271#8246271).

When I enter `pear config-show` These values are returned.

```
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          D:\path\to\xampp\php
User Configuration File        Filename         C:\Windows\pear.ini
System Configuration File      Filename         C:\Windows\pearsys.ini
```

There are no local PEAR files on my machine. When I enter:

```
pear config-set doc_dir D:\path\to\php\pear\docs
```

This is returned

```
config-set: only the layers: "user" or system are supported
```

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ pear help config-set
pear config-set [options] <parameter> <value> [layer]
```

Could it be that you have a space somewhere in your path? If yes, you have to quote that argument.