# Issues while installing pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

Tags: php, pear

I'm trying to tell `pear` that where to find PHPUnit by using this command:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

The output was:

```
Discovering channel pear.phpunit.de over http:// failed with message: channel-add: Cannot open "http://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (File http://pear.phpunit.de:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
))
Trying to discover channel pear.phpunit.de over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.phpunit.de" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (File https://pear.phpunit.de:443/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
)))
```

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

Then I ran `channel-discover` command again. I got same error as shown above.
I even tried these commands:

```
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
```

Output:

```
config-set succeeded
```

Then I tried this command:

```
sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Output:

```
Attempting to discover channel "pear.phpunit.de"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "pear.phpunit.de"...
unknown channel "pear.phpunit.de" in "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
invalid package name/package file "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

So I visited this link:  `https://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml` and it displayed `410 gone` error. Is there any other alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't install phpunit using pear anymore:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

But you can still install it using the phar file:
https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Or using composer:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer

Answer (score 3):

Most people just composer nowadays. But since you seem to be on Ubuntu you can always do:

```
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the phar archive worked for me:

https://github.com/Mayflower/PHP_CodeBrowser

```
wget https://github.com/mayflower/PHP_CodeBrowser/releases/download/1.1.1/phpcb-1.1.1.phar
mv phpcb-1.1.1.phar /usr/local/bin/phpcb
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/phpcb

phpcb --version
PHP_CodeBrowser version 1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

For those on RHEL distros (CentOS/Fedora/ etc) and not yet using composer, you can install phpunit using YUM:

```
yum install phpunit
```