# 'Selenium_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase' not found in c://wamp/bin/php/php5.2.6/PEAR/Extensions/seleniumTestCase.php, line 2'

Tags: phpunit, selenium-rc

I am getting some issue in implementation of Selenium RC with PHP.  This is cause of some path issues. I have successfully installed PHPUnit but I am not able to run the test cases. Each time I facing "class PHPUnit_Extention_SeleniumTestCases not found".

I am following these steps to run .php file to run with selenium RC.

1. Start Selenium RC server.
2. Restart cmd and access the path where PHPUnit has installed means cd C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.6
3. Run PHPUnit --version command, this results PHPUnit version (This also indicated that PHPUnit has been installed successfully in my system.)
4. Prepare WebTest.php file and keep this in php5.2.6 folder (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.6)
5. Open cmd and access path C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.6, and run PHPUnit Webtest .
6. Running this command fires a fatal  error, 'class PHPUnit_Extention_Selenium2TestCases not found in c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.6/PEAR/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php on line 2', while in the above path, all these files have been kept already.

Please look into matter, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PEAR installed?  If you're using WAMP, it doesn't come included with your php, apache, and mysql, so you'll need to install it separately.  See this question: [Installing PEAR on wampserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796554/installing-pear-on-wampserver)